# python replace will not replace "'" with "\'"

Tags: python

```
    dctLineItems = InvFunctions.dctLineItems
    for value in dctLineItems.values():
        iORDER_ID = value[0]
        iITEM_No = value[1]
        iQUANTITY = value[2]
        sTmp = value[3]
        sTmp2 = sTmp.replace("'", "\'", 1)
        #sTmp2 = connPy.escape(sTmp)
        sITEM_Name = sTmp2
        sPART_No = value[4]
        fPRICE = value[5]
        fPRICE = fPRICE.lstrip('$')
        iDOGWOOD = value[6]
        iADVANCED = value[7]
```

I have tested it extensively and replace works for just about anything except what I need it to do. When I try to replace " ' " with " \' " it doesn't do anything. Notice the commented line#8 connPy.escape(sTmp), it doesn't work either but that is going to be a separate question.

Comment: double the backslash, else it only escapes the quote.

Comment: Should you use double scape "\\'" or raw strings r"\'"?

Comment: Maybe you are confused with some other languages when the pair of characters `\x` when `x` is one of the "special characters" like `n`, `t` etc. yields the special character and otherwise *remains unchanged*. In python `\x` *always* produces a single character that either is the special one, or simply `x`. In this case `x = '`. If you want to have the pair of characters you have to escape the backslash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option: using Python's raw strings:

```
>>> "'hello'".replace("'", "\'")
>>> "'hello'"
>>>
>>> "'hello'".replace("'", "\\'")
>>> "\\'hello\\'"
>>>
>>> "'hello'".replace("'", r"\'")  # <- Note the starting r
>>> "\\'hello\\'"
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that the backslash is known in Python as an escape sequence. Python doesn't recognize this as a literal, so you would have to put `\\` instead. The same applies to the single quote (`\'`)

So where you're using your replace function (I'm guessing the 5th line from the top), try typing this:

`sTmp.replace("'", "\\", 1)`